# TypeScript dynamic + expected object keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using **Antd Pro Table** and trying to provide dataSource, so my column list is created Like this:

```
export type DataSourceBaseColumns = {
  subcontractor: MasterAgent | null
  supplier: MasterAgent | null
  product_template: {
    id: number | null
    name: string | null
  } | null
  docfile: {
    order_document_id: string | null
    document_id: number | null
    name: string | null
    url: string | null
  } | null
}

  export type SummaryData = DataSourceBaseColumns & { uuid: string } & Record<
    string,
    number | string | null
  >

  const columns: ProColumns<SummaryData>[] = data.columns.map(
    (column) => ({
      title: column,
      dataIndex: column,
      align: 'left',
    })
  )
```

I expect some fixed object keys like `subcontractor`, `supplier`, `product_template`, `docfile`, and some dynamic keys depending on the BE response. The above code is not working, because I have an error although I have specifically determined what type I expect docfile to be.

> Property `docfile` is incompatible with index signature.
> Type `{ document_id: number; name: string; url: string; order_document_id: string; }` is not assignable to type `string | number | null`.ts(2322)

How can I make it work as expected?

Comment: We are missing definitions for `MasterAgent`, `ProColumns`, and `data`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be important here, problem is that type `SummaryData` for some reason is overwriting `docfile` type from `DataSourceBaseColumns`

Comment: It's important to us because without it we can't really reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show the ProColumns type? Plus where is the error generated? From the `const columns`?